# Notification in Salesforce 1 App

Tags: salesforce1-app, push-notification

There is an Approval process which is triggered (I used only configuration) by a community user to the approver. Once approved, I want a particular community user to get a notification in Salesforce1 Mobile app. How do I achieve this?